# Problema ejecutando un shell en php

Tags: php, shell

Quiero ejecutar un archivo shell desde php mediante este comando:

```
system('./12.sh');
```

Y el contenido de ese archivo shell es el siguiente :

```
  #!/bin/bash

source ~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/activate

python /home/raul-pc/Documentos/codigo/rec_face.py
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa php desde la Terminal todo sale bien usando este comando:

```
cam programa.php
```

Pero lo que quiero es poder ejecutarlo desde el servidor. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Comment: En el servidor puede que las ruta `/home/raul-pc/Documentos/codigo/` no exista? Sería buenos que adjuntes el/los mensajes de error.

Comment: Ese es el problema. Cuando quiero ejecutar el php desde el navegador no pasa nada

Comment: Te sugiero que modifiques el script y agregues en primer termino algo como `echo ejecutando > /tmp/12.log`, luego la llamada al script python  la direcciones también agregando `>> /tmp/12.log` (append), luego de probar, revisa el archivo `/tmp/12.log`

Comment: ya probe y solo imprime 'ejecutando' en el archivo 12.log

Comment: Es raro, yo agregaría un `ls /home/raul-pc/Documentos/codigo/rec_face.py >> /tmp/12.log` despues de la ejecución, para confirmar si existe el path. Por otro lado, que no te muestre ningún registro más en el log puede tener que ver que se ejecuta el Script pero que este no termina nunca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP tiene un método para ejecutar comandos shell. Se llama **[`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php)**:

> Ejecutar un comando mediante el intérprete de comandos y devolver la
>   salida completa como una cadena.

**Sintaxis**

```
string shell_exec ( string $cmd )
```

**Parámetros**

**`cmd`**
El comando que será ejecutado.

**Valores devueltos**

La salida del comando ejecutado o NULL si ocurre un error o el comando no produce ninguna salida.

Nota:
Esta función puede devolver NULL cuando ocurre un error o cuando el programa no produce ninguna salida. No es posible detectar los fallos de ejecución usando esta función. exec() debería usarse cuando sea necesario el acceso al código de salida del programa.

```
Ejemplo #1 Un ejemplo de shell_exec()

<?php
$salida = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$salida</pre>";
?>
```

> Nota: Esta función está deshabilitada cuando PHP se ejecuta en modo
>   seguro.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HHUIA57123)**

```
<?php

$salida = shell_exec('uname -a');
echo $salida;

?>
```

**Resultado**

```
Linux lvps83-169-3-96.dedicated.hosteurope.de 4.4.0-042stab120.16 
#1 SMP Tue Dec 13 20:58:28 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: He estado investigando sobre mi problema y creo que el problema no es el script shell en si, por que cuando pongo comandos mas simples dentro estos se ejecutan normalmente, sino el script python, porque en este script hago uso de la camara web y tambien estoy utilizando opencv. Asi que el verdadero problema creo que es que el navegador no posee permisos para los recursos del sistema. Agradeceria mucho que me ayuden en esa parte porque nose deque manera dar esos permisos.

Comment: @LeonardoRaul La pregunta era sobre cómo ejecutarlo en el servidor: _Pero lo que quiero es poder ejecutarlo desde el servidor. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?_ , de ahí mi respuesta. Si has comprobado que el problema real es algo sobre los permisos creo que sería mejor modificar la pregunta indicando el mensaje de error que recibes de falta de autorización, o bien dar esta por resuelta y plantear una nueva pregunta.